# asciidoctor task as part of gradle build

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have integrated Spring Rest-Docs to my project which uses Gradle for build process. I have configured the asciidoctor but I need to run the tasks when I trigger the `gradle build`.

```
asciidoctor {
  sourceDir 'src/asciidoc'
  dependsOn test
  attributes \
    'snippets': file('target/generated-snippets')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a dependency for the `build` task to the `asciidoctor` task:

```
build.dependsOn asciidoctor
```